# "Switch applications directly" keyboard shortcut for gnome

Tags: shortcut-keys, gnome-shell

In the Gnome settings Keyboard shortcuts, you can bind

- `Switch applications`
- `Switch windows`
- `Switch windows directly`.

[image]

What I'm looking for is `Switch applications directly`. So I want to switch applications, not windows, but by showing the applications directly, not with some kind of overlay.

Is there an extension for this?

Using Ubuntu 20.04 with Gnome 3.36.8.

Comment: A quick "Alt+Tab" will switch applications without showing the overlay.

Comment: @vanadium I know, but often i need to cycle through a few applications to find the right one. I prefer to just see the apps instead of some overlay with icons.

Comment: I see. If this exists, it will indeed be through an extension.

Answer (score -1):

Alt+Esc

Super Key(windows key)+Tab

Comment: This does not switch __without overlay__ on my pc.

Comment: @Epskampie, why downvote? ALt + Esc works without overlay.